# unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker

I am developing an iPad app. I get following error when try to create Archive of it.

> Ld /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LSS-gtlketfveaswhcefyvuepplwjfbu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LSS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/LSS.app/LSS normal armv7
>       cd /Users/macbook/Desktop/LSSCodeMarch22
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -L/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LSS-gtlketfveaswhcefyvuepplwjfbu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LSS/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/macbook/Desktop/LSSCodeMarch22/LSS/CrittercismSDK -L/Users/macbook/Desktop/LSSCodeMarch22/LSS/Airship -F/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LSS-gtlketfveaswhcefyvuepplwjfbu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LSS/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LSS-gtlketfveaswhcefyvuepplwjfbu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LSS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/LSS.build/Debug-iphoneos/LSS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LSS.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -lsqlite3 -framework AudioToolbox -framework Security -framework Foundation -framework CoreTelephony -framework StoreKit -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework CoreText -framework MessageUI -framework UIKit -lUAirship-1.4.0 -lCrittercism_v3_4_9 -o /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LSS-gtlketfveaswhcefyvuepplwjfbu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LSS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/LSS.app/LSS
>
> clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
>
> clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

Can anyone please help me in dealing with this problem?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that one of the third party APIs being used in the app was not compatible with latest iOS (6.1). I removed that framework from the list of frameworks and it worked.